# Cannot reshape numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I try to convolve an image using the function `convolve`, which is written below
(It's `conv2d_fast` from [Python image convolution using NumPy only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587303/python-image-convolution-using-numpy-only)):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def convolve(img, krn):
    is0, is1 = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
    ks0, ks1 =  krn.shape[0], krn.shape[1]
    rs0, rs1 = is0 - ks0 + 1, is1 - ks1 + 1

    ix0 = np.arange(ks0)[:, None] + np.arange(rs0)[None, :]
    ix1 = np.arange(ks1)[:, None] + np.arange(rs1)[None, :]

    res = krn[:, None, :, None] * img[(ix0.ravel()[:, None], ix1.ravel()[None, :])].reshape(ks0, rs0, ks1, rs1)
    res = res.transpose(1, 3, 0, 2).reshape(rs0, rs1, -1).sum(axis = -1)

    return res
```

My code for image processing:

```
kernel = np.asarray([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,1,1]])
in_image = Image.open('image.png')
numpydata = np.asarray(in_image)
array_img = convolve(numpydata ,kernel)
```

I was faced with the error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 29025144 into shape (3,673,3,1198)

I google it and find
[Cannot reshape array of size into shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028853/cannot-reshape-array-of-size-into-shape)

but in my case 29025144 divide by a whole for 3*673*3*1198
29025144 = 4 *(3*673*3*1198)

Can you help me, please)

Comment: When you say you want to reshape an array to (3, 673, 3, 1198), it means you have exactly 7256286 elements. Not x times that. But maybe you want to add another dimension with -1? This will use the remainder for that axis, e.g.,  (3, 673, 3, 1198, -1) will end up being (3, 673, 3, 1198, 4). This is all addressed in the question you linked, so how does it not answer your question?

Comment: I was going  to step through that problem line, `res = ...reshape(...)`, but quickly got lost in the mix of shapes, especially the `img` indexing.  This isn't a `googling` issue.  It's a matter of getting the mix of shapes, particularly the total number of elements, right.

Comment: Another thought, what `numpydata.shape`?  Is it, for example a 4 channel color image?  Your shapes only focus on the h/w dimensions.  Questions like this need full information - traceback along with the shape and dtype of all arrays in quesitons.

Comment: Before "googling it", di you read (or reread) the `np.reshape` docs?